# SRX Point-To-Site IPsec VPN Setup

Tags: ipsec, linux, juniper-srx

I'm trying to setup an IPsec VPN tunnel between a Debian Jessie system running strongSwan and an SRX. The end goal is to use the Debian host as a reverse-proxy for hosts behind the SRX, which I assume will require a split-tunnel.

The Debian host is `debian.example.com/1.2.3.4`.

The SRX is at `srx.example.com` and has a dynamically assigned IP which I've replaced with `5.6.7.8` below.

Both sides seem to think the SA is up, but I am unable to ping anything in the `192.168.1.0/24` subnet from the Debian host.

SRX:

```
root@srx# run show security ike security-associations
Index   State  Initiator cookie  Responder cookie  Mode           Remote Address
3981725 UP     b1cbd62070dd2779  f49d3bd11b69a018  IKEv2          1.2.3.4
```

Debian:

```
# ipsec status srx.example.com
Security Associations (1 up, 0 connecting):
srx.example.com[1]: ESTABLISHED 32 minutes ago, 1.2.3.4[debian.example.com]...5.6.7.8[srx.example.com]
srx.example.com{1}:  INSTALLED, TUNNEL, ESP SPIs: ca2f0887_i 516e8cf8_o
srx.example.com{1}:   192.168.2.0/24 === 192.168.1.0/24
# ip -s xfrm policy list src 192.168.2.0/24
src 192.168.2.0/24 dst 192.168.1.0/24 uid 0
        dir out action allow index 2593 priority 2883 ptype main share any flag  (0x00000000)
        lifetime config:
          limit: soft (INF)(bytes), hard (INF)(bytes)
          limit: soft (INF)(packets), hard (INF)(packets)
          expire add: soft 0(sec), hard 0(sec)
          expire use: soft 0(sec), hard 0(sec)
        lifetime current:
          0(bytes), 0(packets)
          add 2016-08-16 18:14:21 use -
        tmpl src 1.2.3.4 dst 5.6.7.8
                proto esp spi 0x00000000(0) reqid 1(0x00000001) mode tunnel
                level required share any
                enc-mask ffffffff auth-mask ffffffff comp-mask ffffffff
```

SRX config:

```
interfaces {
    interface-range interfaces-trust {
        member fe-0/0/0;
        member fe-0/0/1;
        member fe-0/0/2;
        unit 0 {
            family ethernet-switching {
                vlan {
                    members vlan-trust;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    fe-0/0/7 {
        unit 0 {
            family inet {
                dhcp {
                    update-server;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    st0 {
        unit 0 {
            family inet;
        }
    }
    vlan {
        unit 100 {
            family inet {
                address 192.168.1.1/24;
            }
        }
    }
}
security {
    ike {
        proposal ike-vpn-proposal {
            authentication-method pre-shared-keys;
            dh-group group24;
            authentication-algorithm sha-256;
            encryption-algorithm aes-128-cbc;
        }
        policy ike-vpn-policy {
            mode aggressive;
            proposals ike-vpn-proposal;
            pre-shared-key ascii-text "$9$KJiWxdaJDkqf7-qfQzAtNdb"; ## SECRET-DATA
        }
        gateway vpn-local-gw {
            ike-policy ike-vpn-policy;
            address 1.2.3.4;
            local-identity hostname srx.example.com;
            remote-identity hostname debian.example.com;
            external-interface fe-0/0/7.0;
            version v2-only;
        }
    }
    ipsec {
        proposal ipsec-vpn-proposal {
            protocol esp;
            authentication-algorithm hmac-sha-256-128;
            encryption-algorithm aes-128-cbc;
        }
        policy ipsec-vpn-policy {
            perfect-forward-secrecy {
                keys group24;
            }
            proposals ipsec-vpn-proposal;
        }
        vpn vpn {
            bind-interface st0.0;
            ike {
                gateway vpn-local-gw;
                proxy-identity {
                    local 192.168.1.0/24;
                    remote 192.168.2.0/24;
                }
                ipsec-policy ipsec-vpn-policy;
            }
            establish-tunnels immediately;
        }
    }
    policies {
        from-zone trust to-zone untrust {
            policy trust-to-untrust {
                match {
                    source-address any;
                    destination-address any;
                    application any;
                }
                then {
                    permit;
                }
            }
        }
        from-zone untrust to-zone trust {
            policy untrust-to-trust {
                match {
                    source-address any;
                    destination-address any;
                    application any;
                }
                then {
                    deny;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    zones {
        security-zone trust {
            host-inbound-traffic {
                system-services {
                    all;
                }
                protocols {
                    all;
                }
            }
            interfaces {
                vlan.100;
            }
        }
        security-zone untrust {
            screen untrust-screen;
            interfaces {
                fe-0/0/7.0 {
                    host-inbound-traffic {
                        system-services {
                            dhcp;
                            ike;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        security-zone vpn {
            interfaces {
                st0.0;
            }
        }
    }
}
vlans {
    vlan-trust {
        vlan-id 100;
        l3-interface vlan.100;
    }
}
```

Debian strongSwan config:

```
# ipsec.conf - strongSwan IPsec configuration file

config setup

# Add connections here.
conn srx.example.com
    auto=start
    keyexchange=ikev2
    authby=secret
    ike=aes128-sha256-modp2048s256
    ikelifetime=3h
    esp=aes128-sha256
    leftid=@debian.example.com
    rightid=@srx.example.com
    left=1.2.3.4
    right=srx.example.com
    leftsubnet=192.168.2.0/24
    rightsubnet=192.168.1.0/24

include /var/lib/strongswan/ipsec.conf.inc
```

Update:

I think I may be missing the routes to make things work.

SRX:

```
root@srx> show security flow session destination-prefix 192.168.1.0
Total sessions: 0

root@dravis> show route table inet.0 brief

inet.0: 5 destinations, 5 routes (5 active, 0 holddown, 0 hidden)
+ = Active Route, - = Last Active, * = Both

0.0.0.0/0          *[Access-internal/12] 22:20:39
                    > to 5.6.7.1 via fe-0/0/7.0
5.6.7.0/24         *[Direct/0] 10w3d 12:43:15
                    > via fe-0/0/7.0
5.6.7.8/32         *[Local/0] 10w3d 12:43:15
                      Local via fe-0/0/7.0
192.168.1.0/24     *[Direct/0] 4w6d 13:21:42
                    > via vlan.100
192.168.1.1/32     *[Local/0] 10w3d 12:43:40
                      Local via vlan.100
```

Debian:

```
$ netstat -nr
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags   MSS Window  irtt Iface
0.0.0.0         1.2.3.1         0.0.0.0         UG        0 0          0 eth0
10.10.0.0       0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U         0 0          0 eth0
1.2.3.0         0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 eth0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The final step was the routing.

SRX:

```
routing-options {
    static {
        route 192.168.2.0/24 next-hop st0.0;
    }
}
security {
    policies {
        from-zone vpn to-zone trust {
            policy vpn-to-trust {
                match {
                    source-address any;
                    destination-address any;
                    application any;
                }
                then {
                    permit;
                }
            }
        }
        from-zone trust to-zone vpn {
            policy trust-to-vpn {
                match {
                    source-address any;
                    destination-address any;
                    application any;
                }
                then {
                    permit;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Debian:

```
# ip addr add 192.168.2.2/24 dev eth0
# ip route add to 192.168.1.0/24 via 192.168.2.2 src 192.168.2.2
```

Answer (score 1):

On the SRX you have no security policy configured between the vpn zone (which is where your tunnel interface st0.0 resides) and the trust zone.

Add the following and you should be up and running:

```
set security policies from-zone vpn to-zone trust policy vpn-to-trust match source-address any
set security policies from-zone vpn to-zone trust policy vpn-to-trust match destination-address any
set security policies from-zone vpn to-zone trust policy vpn-to-trust match application any
set security policies from-zone vpn to-zone trust policy vpn-to-trust then permit
```

Comment: I added this to my config, but I'm still not able to ping any of the hosts in 192.168.1.0/24 from the cloud host.

Comment: Run "show security flow session destination-prefix 192.168.1.0" and look for sessions from the Debian box - do you see any sessions being generated?  I assume FreeSWAN is putting a route in the Debian box telling it to use the IPSEC tunnel for the 192.168.1.0/24 range.  Likewise, on the SRX you will need a route back to the Debian box via st0.0 otherwise the traffic will just following your default gateway.

Comment: Added output from that command to the main comment. There don't seem to be any routes on either end, so I guess that's the problem. Unfortunately I have no idea how to set that part up.